# How to save pixels displayed on the screen in mutable Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, pixel, bitmapimage

I am trying to make an Android aplication, in which you take a foto. You zoom in to a desired region of the foto then you copy this region into a Bitmap for further processing.

I tried to make a new mutable Bitmap to copy the Bitmap from ImageView object that holds the picture but I receive out of memory error.
Another problem is how do I copy only the desired region?
I have the impresion that if you copy one by one each pixel you copy the whole picture.

I am using Android 2.2.1 API level 7.
I need only some tips to search for, till now the search of Bitmap documentation was unsuccesfull.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the data hidden in the cache:

```
mImageView1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mImageView1.buildDrawingCache();
mImageView1.getDrawingCache();//this is the data I need it.
```